# How to do Magento order refund to individual items?

Tags: magento

How can we do refund on individual items in magento order?

For Example.

I have purchaged three items 1,2,3 in single magento order.
Now I want to do refund on item 1 from magento admin.
In magento there is option of refund but it is order specific 
So is it possible to do items wise refund in magento?
If possible then please can you give me some suggestion and related tutorials or any extensions.

Please help me

Thank you

Comment: Asking for tutorials or extensions is off-topic on SO.

Comment: You can provide tutorials or plugin anyone which you have knowledge

Comment: Asking for them is off-topic, so you shouldn't ask for them here.